# How to automatically mount storage card in Windows CE 6

Tags: windows, windows-ce

I have the following problem: on a GPS device (Mio 6800, Windows CE6) the external storage card (micro SD) is seen by Windows Explorer ONLY if I *manually mount* it from Control Panel. My goal is to have the Storage Card mounted when Windows boots.
I tried in Registry some keys suggested by MSDN site but does not work. Can anyone provide a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some registry entries I am currently using:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\SDCARD\ClientDrivers\Class\SDMemory_Class\High_Capacity]
   "Dll"="SDMemory.dll"   
   "Prefix"="DSK"
   "Profile"="SDMemory"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\SDCARD\ClientDrivers\Class\SDMemory_Class]
   "Dll"="SDMemory.dll"
   "Prefix"="DSK"
   "Profile"="SDMemory"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\SDMemory]
    "Name"="SD Memory Card"
    "Folder"="SD"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\SDMemory\FATFS]
   "AutoMount"=dword:1
```

Modify them according to the file system of the card. For example if you are using EXFAT you should set the "AutoMount" value to 1 for EXFAT entry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\StorageManager\Profiles\SDMemory\EXFAT]
   "AutoMount"=dword:1
```

Also, make sure that after restarting the device these registry entries are still there. Maybe you need to flush the registry after you add the entries.

Hope this helps.